# Installer Stuck At "creating ext4 file system"

Tags: system-installation, 15.10

Info: Ubuntu Livecd 15.10.
The Screen where it's stuck at:
[image]

Disk Utility: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens to me all the time.

To solve this, *I format concerned linux partitions* ( `Filesystem Partition 5` and `Swap partition 6` in your case) *from disk utility ie `gnome-disks` manually.*

To do so you must select `Try ubuntu` instead of `Install ubuntu` after booting from bootable cd/usb.